# Populating data from Oracle database into underwriting Workbook in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, oracle11g, xls

I am working on an assignment where it is required to populate data from Oracle Database into underwriting MS Excel Worksheet so that our analysts can review the data and pick the desired options for the customers.

One way of doing it is to load the data into a dataset and loop through and populate the spreadsheet.

Any of you guys using any 3rd party APIs for doing this task in a efficient manner.

Appreciate if you could help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very specific, what type of data? 
Is it just the raw data, simplified or have to be presented in a specific way (X info on one worksheet, Y info on another)? 
Are you generating statistics and charts on top of this?

What do you mean by efficient? 
Quick for you to implement, easy for the analysts or the application itself being efficient?

In general this library is probably a good place to start. It makes populating excel workbook objects straight forward and has a reliable export mechanism. You may find that you don't need to worry about implementation after utilizing this.
http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (not so clean) way of reading

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDb.OleDbConnection(("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + ("data source=C:\\MyFolder\myworkbook.xls; " + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")));
// Select the data from Sheet1 of the workbook.
OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Sheet1$]", conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ada.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
conn.Close();
```

You would need to replace

> C:\MyFolder\myworkbook.xls;

into your file path

and

> Sheet1

with your worksheet name for it to work. A reference to Oledb has to be added into your project.

Comment: There are a lot of 3rd party API's and Microsoft's own API's for achieving this.